# Remove layers from OSM file using osmfilter

Tags: openstreetmap, osmfilter

I am working with big OSM file (1GB) and 24 GB converted. How can I filter small objects to load a map into Maperative. I try to run

```
osmfilter.exe au2.o5a --keep="bBoxWeight>=10" -o=out.o5m
```

but I get a zero size file? Any another variants?

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129978/15183 osmconvert needs the option `--add-bboxweight-tags` to get the bboxweight tags.

You can chain osmfilter and osmconvert together, so your steps will be

```
osmconvert --add-bboxweight-tags ...
osmfilter --keep"bBoxWeight>10" ...
```